# How can I detect the position of touch input on the track pad in OSX?

Tags: macos, mouselistener, trackpad

I have a magic trackpad 2 and I'm hoping to write an app that can read the raw touch data and re-position the mouse on touch start to make it behave more like a tablet than a trackpad.

Step 1 is reading raw touch input. I need to hook the "user put their finger on the trackpad" event and get the absolute x/y.

In googling I've found several solutions in swift and objc, but they're all like 6+ years old and I can't get any of them to build. Honestly, if there is an even lower level api I could use (something akin to win32 apis) that would be even better.

Any advise on where to start on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check out `NSEvent` documentation related to tablet events?

Comment: `I've found several solutions` Which ones? Maybe we can help you adapt these solutions.

Comment: @Eimantas do track pads generate tablet events?

Comment: See [Touch Events Represent Fingers on the Trackpad](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW1).